# invalid input syntax for type interval: "missing"

Tags: postgresql, select, timestamp, bigint

I am working with **PostgreSQL 8.4.4**. My problem is, I am calculating time difference in days-hours-minuts from two bigint values. I am converting those values to timestamp and then calculating the difference. I am getting the difference for the values that are present in table. But for those that return `NULL` or not present in table, I want result as 'Missing'. When I add this in query, I get above error. Following is the query I am using:

```
select 
   case when exists (SELECT age(to_timestamp(incepted_date), to_timestamp(invoice_pay_date)) 
                    from transactions_transactions where id = 4275) 
   then (SELECT age(to_timestamp(incepted_date), to_timestamp(invoice_pay_date)) 
                    from transactions_transactions where id = 4275)   
   else 'missing'
end
```

Comment: try like this `select coalesce(nullif(age(to_timestamp(incepted_date), to_timestamp(invoice_pay_date))::text,''),'Missing')
FROM transactions_transactions
WHERE id = 4275` or this - http://hastebin.com/iyaxavilef.sql

Comment: Thank you very much @winged panther for your quick response and the solution is working as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the combination of [coalesce()](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-COALESCE-NVL-IFNULL) and [nullif()](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-NULLIF) function to achieve the result instead of using `CASE-WHEN` like below

```
SELECT coalesce(nullif(age(to_timestamp(incepted_date), to_timestamp(invoice_pay_date))::TEXT, ''), 'Missing')
FROM transactions_transactions
WHERE id = 4275
```